# Linear regression for multi-class classification

Tags: regression, classification, linear-model

- Linear regression can be used for binary classification where it competes with logistic regression. While the fitted values from linear regression are not restricted to lie between 0 and 1, unlike those from logistic regression that are interpreted as class probabilities, linear regression can still successfully assign class labels based on some threshold on fitted values (e.g. a threshold of 0.5).
- Logistic regression can be used for multi-class classification by applying it repeatedly as one-against-the rest classification.

Can linear regression be used for multi-class classification in the same way (one against all, repeat for each class)?
Or is there some inherent feature that would to make it fail?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Overview

I don't think that solving classification problems using linear regression is usually the best approach (see notes below), but it *can* be done. For multiclass problems, [multinomial logistic regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_logistic_regression) would typically be used rather than a combination of multiple regular logistic regression models. By analogy, one could instead use least squares linear regression with multiple outputs.

#### Approach

Suppose we have training data $\big\{ (x_i,y_i) \big\}_{i=1}^n$ where each $x_i \in \mathbb{R}^d$ is an input point with class label $y_i$. Say there are $k$ classes. We can represent each label as a binary vector $y_i \in \{0,1\}^{k}$, whose $j$th entry is $1$ if point $i$ is a member of class $j$, otherwise $0$. The regression problem is to predict the vector-valued class labels as a linear function of the inputs, such that the squared error is minimized:

$$\min_W \ \sum_{i=1}^n \|y_i - W x_i\|^2$$

where $W \in \mathbb{R}^{k \times d}$ is a weight matrix and $\|\cdot\|^2$ is the squared $\ell_2$ norm. The inputs should contain a constant feature (i.e. one element of $x_i$ should always be $1$), so we don't have to worry about extra bias/intercept terms.

To predict the class for a new input $x$, compute the vector $a = W x$, where $a_i$ is the projection of the input onto the the $i$th row of $W$ (the weights for the $i$th class). Then, some rule can be applied to map the projections to a single class. For example, we could choose the class with the maximal projection: $\arg \max_i a_i$. This is loosely analogous to selecting the most probable class in multinomial logistic regression.

#### Example

Here's a plot of the decision boundaries learned from a set of 2d points, using the above method. Colors represent true class labels.

[image]

#### Notes

This method sacrifices the principled, probabilistic approach used in multinomial logistic regression. The squared error is also an odd choice for classification problems, where we're predicting binary values (or binary vectors, as above). The issue is that the squared error penalizes large outputs, even when these *ought* to be considered correct. For example, suppose the true class label is $[1,0,0]$. Outputting $[2,0,0]$ (which should correspond to high confidence in the correct class) is just as costly as outputting $[0,0,1]$ (which corresponds to high confidence in the wrong class). Even if one is willing to abandon probabilistic models, there are other loss functions designed specifically for classification, like the hinge loss used in support vector machines. The main benefit of the squared error is computational efficiency. But, this doesn't seem particularly necessary in most cases, given that we can routinely solve much more complicated problems involving massive datasets. Nevertheless, one does sometimes see the squared error used in the literature for classification problems (apparently with success). [Least squares support vector machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least-squares_support-vector_machine) are the most prominent example that comes to mind.

#### Code

Matlab code to generate the example plot above. Matrices are transposed relative to the text above, since points and labels are stored as rows.

```matlab
%% generate toy dataset

% how many points and classes
n = 300;
k = 3;

% randomly choose class labels (integers from 1 to k)
c = randi(k, n, 1);

% convert labels to binary indicator vectors
% Y(i,j) = 1 if point i in class j, else 0
Y = full(sparse((1:n)', c, 1));

% mean of input points in each class
mu = [
    0, 0;
    4, 0;
    0, 4
];

% sample 2d input points from gaussian distributions
% w/ class-specific means
X = randn(n, 2) + mu(c, :);

% add a column of ones
X = [X, ones(n,1)];


%% fit weights using least squares
W = X \ Y;


%% out-of-sample prediction

% generate new test points on a grid covering the training points
[xtest2, xtest1] = ndgrid( ...
    linspace(min(X(:,2)), max(X(:,2)), 501), ...
    linspace(min(X(:,1)), max(X(:,1)), 501) ...
);
X_test = [xtest1(:), xtest2(:)];

% add a column of ones
X_test = [X_test, ones(size(X_test,1), 1)];

% project test points onto weights
A_test = X_test * W;

% predict class for each test point
% choose class w/ maximal projection
[~, c_test] = max(A_test, [], 2);


%% plot

% plot decision boundary
% using contour plot of predicted class labels at grid points
figure;
contour(xtest1, xtest2, reshape(c_test, size(xtest1)), 'color', 'k');

% plot training data colored by true class label
hold on;
scatter(X(:,1), X(:,2), [], c, 'filled');
```

Comment: Thank you. The question is a theoretical one; I have not considered actually using linear regression for multi-class classification. But since [Hastie and Tibshirani's slides](https://lagunita.stanford.edu/c4x/HumanitiesScience/StatLearning/asset/classification.pdf) accompanying "Introduction to Statistical Learning", and probably the book itself (I do not remember exactly) seem to justify (or at least consider seriously) linear regression for binary classification, my question followed naturally. The book notes that multinomial regression is little used and suggests LDA instead.

Comment: The books says on p. 137-138: *The two-class logistic regression models discussed in the previous sections have multiple-class extensions, **but in practice they tend not to be used all that often**. One of the reasons is that the method we discuss in the next section, discriminant analysis, is popular for multiple-class classiﬁcation. So we do not go into the details of multiple-class logistic regression here, but simply note that such an approach is possible, and that software for it is available in R.*

Comment: Could you add the code used for generating the graph? I think it could be helpful. Just FYI, I have also asked a couple more questions on classification recently: [Failing to recover true parameters in simulations of multinomial logit](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/429840) and [Evaluating classification results when importance of correct classification varies with class](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/429831) with no answers so far.

Comment: @RichardHardy Interestingly, multinomial logistic regression is making a big comeback. Or, at least, it's used as a component in some current, state-of-the-art methods. For example, fitting a deep neural net with softmax output layer and log loss (the typical setup) is equivalent to jointly learning a multinomial logistic regression model on top of a nonlinear transformation.

Comment: @RichardHardy. I edited to include matlab code for the example. I could post python instead if that would be helpful but, alas, I'm not familiar with R.

Answer (score 1):

I think using linear regression for multi-classes classify is totally doable.

First, let's recall that the backbone of logistic regression itself is linear regression. Following is the logistic function, but it is really just a linear function wrapped sigmoid function. When we train logistic regression, we are really just tweaking the parameter of the linear function inside the sogmoid function.
[image]

Here I would like to demonstrate with sklearn in python:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression, LinearRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X, y = load_iris(return_X_y=True)
X_train,X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.2)


## logistic regression
clf_logistic = LogisticRegression(random_state=0,max_iter=1000).fit(X_train, y_train)
#print(f"score of logistic method: {clf_logistic.score(X_test, y_test)}")
### the following lines do the exact same thing
y0 = np.argmax(X_test.dot(clf_logistic.coef_.T)+clf_logistic.intercept_, axis=-1)
y1 = clf_logistic.predict(X_test)
assert np.array_equal(y0,y1) == True
acc_logistic = np.sum(y0 == y_test)/y_test.shape[0]
print(f"accuracy of logistic method: {acc_logistic}")

## linear regression
clf_linear = LinearRegression().fit(X_train, y_train)
#print(f"score of logistic method: {clf_linear.score(X_test, y_test)}")
y2 = np.round(X_test.dot(clf_linear.coef_.T)+clf_linear.intercept_)
y3 = np.round(clf_linear.predict(X_test))
assert np.array_equal(y2,y3) == True
acc_linear = np.sum(y2 == y_test)/y_test.shape[0]
print(f"accuracy of linear method: {acc_linear}")
```

output:

```
accuracy of logistic method: 0.9333
accuracy of linear method: 1.0
```

As to which one is better, I don't know the exact answer, it may depend on the datasets.

comments:

What the python code above does is using logistic and linear regression to classify iris into 3 categories (0,1,2). Each iris data has 4 features and 1 label. Logistic regression used one vs rest to train the data and predict the result, you can look into the shape of  clf_logistic.coef_, and clf_logistic.intercept_. However, linear regression doesn't use one vs rest (you may aslo look at the shape of clf_linear.coef_, clf_linear.intercept_), it directly predicts a numerical value, simply round float point prediction result to int, you will get the predicted label. It works well, as you can see from the printed accuracy. My understanding is that even though linear regression doesn't use one vs rest, but it works in a similar way to a single neuron like  wx + b

Comment: Thanks for your answer! What does your demonstration do (translated from Python to English)?

Comment: @RichardHardy could you see my comments in my answer

Comment: Thank you and +1.